# Theme displays icons over some fields

Tags: 10.04, icons, themes

I'm using Ubuntu server 10.04, and I work using ssh X11 redirect.

I've installed Ambiance themes in it, but now I have some weird behavior in some components: Seems like some icons over the fields.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a desperate attempt to solve this problem, I installed the following packages on the remote machine:

gtk2-engines-sapwood
gtk2-engines-murrine
community-themes
gtk2-engines-nodoka
murrine-themes
shiki-colors
gtk2-engines-pixbuf

I also copied all the folder ~/.themes/elementary-borderless from the local computer, to the remote machine.

This actions resolved the problem however I can't say for sure what's really needed.